# Pipenv not recognizing Pyenv version?

Tags: python, pyenv, pipenv

I have Python 3.7.0 installed, but for a specific Django project, I would like to use Python 3.6.5. Using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for this purpose, on my Macbook Pro I ran `brew install pyenv`, followed by `pyenv install 3.6.5` and, in the project's root directory, `pyenv local 3.6.5`. I've verified that Python version `3.6.5` is active:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ cat .python-version
3.6.5
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.6.5 (set by /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/dev/lucy2/lucy-web/.python-version)
```

The `Pipfile` I'm using is similar to the following:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6.5"
```

However, when I run `pipenv shell`, I get that it 'defaults' to my system version, python 3.7.0:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ pipenv shell
Loading .env environment variables...
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.6.5, but you are using 3.7.0 (/Users/k/.local/share/v/l/bin/python).
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
bash-3.2$  . /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/bin/activate
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$
```

Now, if I try to run `python manage.py shell` to run the Django project's shell, I get a `SyntaxError` which I suspect is germane to Python 3.7, since I'm sure this was working before:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/apps.py", line 10, in ready
    from .admin import patch_admin
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib import admin
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 151
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

The root cause of this, however, I believe is that it is being run in Python 3.7.0 and not in Python 3.6.5 as desired.

Are `pipenv` and `pyenv` not 'compatible' with each other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pipenv is aware of Pyenv, but it doesn't automatically use the same Python version unless you tell it to do that. There is a note about this in the [Pipenv docs](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#pipenv-does-not-respect-pyenvs-global-and-local-python-versions).

You can either tell Pipenv to use a specific Python version, like

```
pipenv install --python 3.6.5
```

or you can set an environment variable to default to the Pyenv version, like

```
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"
```

Comment: Note that your use of `PIPEVN_PYTHON` is not how it was intended. See this [comment](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4064#issuecomment-631115062)

Answer (score 4):

I noticed what the problem was after downgrading my system-wide Python from 3.7.0 to 3.6.5 and still getting the same error. Once `pipenv` has created a virtualenv, it won't change it according to your current `pyenv` version, but if you delete the virtualenv and create a new one, it will 'pick up' the correct version.

Comment: Considering the original question, this is the correct answer. With the given `Pipfile` re-creating the virtualenv would solve the problem:
`pipenv --rm && pipenv install`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on MacOS.  I installed python 3.6.5 this way:

**Install a specific python version using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):**

```
pyenv install 3.6.5
```

**Create an environment using `pipenv` with the `--python` parameter along with the location of the python version:**

```
pipenv --python /Users/<<Your_User>>/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python3.6
```

If ever you encounter issues relating to `_sqlite3`, you can check this [pyenv ticket](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/108) for the solution.

**Use `pipenv run` to execute commands inside the created environment:**

```
pipenv run python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several different directions in how to setup the .bashrc (even in the pyenv documentation). This one worked for me

```sh
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Install python 3.6.5 using `pyenv install 3.6.5`

Export new installed python version to PATH

`export PATH=${PYENV_PYTHON_VERSIONS_HOME}/3.6.5/bin`

Now in 'Piplock' specify the same version.

`[requires]
 python_version = "3.6.5"`

Finally, run remove previous virtualenv and rebuild again.

`pipenv --rm`

`pipenv install --dev`.