# Pipenv not recognizing shims for PyEnv python installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv

I'm attempting to use pipenv and pyenv to create a virtual environment using python 3.9.0 for a project, but am not able to get pipenv to recognize the version of python 3.9.0 installed by pyenv.  Oddly, using pyenv python 3.8.6 works just as expected, and I'm specifying the specific python I want pipenv to use, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209653/7385884).

I'm running Catalina 10.15.7 and had a coworker reproduce this exact same behavior on his machine.

Both Pipenv and pyenv have been installed via Homebrew. I have since tried uninstalling homebrew Pipenv and reinstalling with pip, with the same results.

### To Reproduce

I successfully ran `pyenv install 3.9.0`, and when I run `pyenv versions`, I see:

- system
- 3.8.6
- 3.9.0

Just as I'd expect.

Inside my working directory, I run `pyenv local 3.9.0` to switch my local version of python, followed by `pyenv version`, which returns returns:

> 3.9.0 (set by /Users/my-name/myproject)

indicating that the local version was set.

To double check, running `pyenv which python` returns:

> /Users/my-name/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python

Now, if I run `pipenv install --python 3.9.0` I get the following:

[image: pipenv install --python 3.9.0]

This already is suspect, since 3.9.0 is my local version already. If I respond with `y`, I get:

[image: not available on path apparently]

Which seems odd, as when I run `python`, I get to python 3.9.0, so clearly it *is* on my path. A Pipfile is not created for me, and I don't get a pipenv virtual environment.

Now, if instead I run `pipenv install --python $PIPENV_PYTHON`, which should in theory use the version of python on my path (which, again, should be 3.9.0), I get this:

[image: mismatched versions]

Notice how it says "using /users/..../python (3.9.0) to create virtualenv", which is correct, however the next line down says "created virtual environment CPYTHON3.8.6...".

Now, if I repeat the above steps using python 3.8.6, everything works fine.

Additionally, if I specify  `pipenv --python ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python3.9`, that also seems to work fine -- so for some reason it's not respecting the version, but it is respecting the binary.

The same is true if I run `pipenv install --python $(pyenv which python)`, since it's effectively the same thing as the above command.

For reference my environment vars:

- `PIP_PYTHON_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/bin/python` <- perhaps this is a problem?
- `PIPENV_ACTIVE=1`
- `PIPENV_PYTHON=/Users/myname/.pyenv/shims/python`
- `PYENV_ROOT=/Users/myname/.pyenv`

And my `$PATH` starts with `PATH=/Users/my-name/.pyenv/shims:`

I *do* happen to have python 3.8 and python 3.9 installed via homebrew as well, however I'm not trying to use these, and since my path leads off with the shims, I feel like this should not be a problem.  Running `which python3` and `which python` both point to the "shims" folder.

### Summary

Pipenv is not respecting my pyenv shims, despite the fact that my PYENV_ROOT and my PATH are set correctly.  Running `pipenv install --python $(pyenv which python)` works, specifying a python version does not.

Is this a problem with pipenv, or pyenv, or something that I'm doing?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [pipenv docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/diagnose/#pipenv-does-not-respect-pyenvs-global-and-local-python-versions):

> Pipenv by default uses the Python it is installed against to create
> the virtualenv. You can set the `--python` option to `$(pyenv which python)` to use your current pyenv interpreter.

It was probably using your system python versions rather than your shims

Comment: Agreed, and doing that *does* work (it's the same as me manually pointing to the binary), however the docs also say to change `pipenv_python` to the shims/python directory, as well as mentioning that you should be able to specify an installed version with `pipenv install --python x.x.x`.  So something still isn't working -- I'd expect to be able to have this work automatically via the env var or at least with me specifying the version number.

Comment: I suppose the short version of that comment would be "I agree, it's not using my shims.  Why not?".  That's ultimately what I would like for it to do.