# Why Pipenv doesn't respect python version when using python from pyenv?

Tags: pipenv, pyenv

After upgrading my Ubuntu from 18.04 (with python 3.8.0) to Ubuntu 22.04 (with default python 3.10) I had to install python 3.8 to be able to perform continual package upgrades on my project.

The python 3.8 was installed using pyenv. The pyenv setup is as follows:

```bash
$ cat .bashrc
...

# https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209653/955422
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python3.8"

# https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#configuration-with-environment-variables
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true
```

when running `pipenv lock` the `Pipfile.lock` suggested to remove [`backports.zoneinfo`](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/) while on python 3.8 it is still required by celery and kombu.

Also the `pyproj` was suggested to be upgraded from 3.5.0 to 3.6.0 even-though [pyproj 3.6.0 requires python 3.9](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/history.html).

In Pipfile there is following spec:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

After the `pipenv lock` the `pipenv sync` fails with error that pyproj 3.6.0 cannot be found. This means that now pipenv respects the pytohn 3.8 limitation.

How do I make pipenv using pyenv respect the specified python version limitation when locking dependencies? Any help would be appreciated.